# Fields_for form fields not displaying in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class Rfsestimation shown below:

```
class Rfsestimation < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :rfstaskset
has_one :rfsnote
enum request_type: [:front_end, :back_end, :front_end_and_back_end]
enum band_type: [:Simple, :Medium, :High, :Complex, :VComplex, :Outside_AD]
**accepts_nested_attributes_for :rfstaskset**
**accepts_nested_attributes_for :rfsnote**

validates_presence_of :number, :name, :date_of_estimation, :request_type_id, :band_id, :hours_per_day, :estimated_start_date, :estimated_end_date, :message => "Should be present"



validates_numericality_of :number


end
```

Please see the two lines for association above marked in bold. I am attempting to create the associated objects, Rfsnote and Rfstask through fields_for shown in below form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :rfstaskset do |rfs_task| %>
```

However the fields which are supposed to appear do not appear as expected. But if i use rfstasksets, as below, the form fields appear as expected.

What might be the reason for this?

```
<%= f.fields_for :rfstasksets do |rfs_task| %>
```

Comment: What are you doing in your controller ? `@rfsestimation.build_rfstaskset` ?

Comment: is something like that necessary ?

Comment: I have only the below line of code:   def new
     @rfsestimation = Rfsestimation.new in the controller

Comment: Yes, that's necessary, you have to build the associated object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not building the associated object in your controller.
You `new` action need to look like this:

```
def new
  @rfsestimation = Rfsestimation.new
  @rfsestimation.build_rfstaskset
end
```

Comment: unknown attribute: rfsestimation_id.. I am seeing this error now. I am trying to find out why this is happening. But however still wondering why using the plural displays the form fields.

Comment: rfs_estimation_id.. I had this attribute in my Rfstaskset model i changed it to rfsestimation_id and the issue has now been resolved.

Comment: Did you add `rfsestimation_id` in `rfstasksets` table? And when you are using `rfstasksets` instead of `rfstaskset`,  it's no more relating it with Rfstaskset model.